# how to get the exactly mysql query of unbook rooms in hotel booking system?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing project of hotel booking system in php and mysql
I created the rooms table which is below

```
room_no| roo_id | room_type
 D1     |  1     | Deluxe
 R1     |  2     | AC
 R2     |  3     | Non Ac
 C1     |  4     | Cottage
```

this table is about rooms represent total rooms in hotel.

this is customer_booking table,

```
customer_id | Cust_name | email | Address | room_type | room_no| cost|check_in | check_out
1 | satyawan |ss@gmail.com| xy | AC       |  R1    |5000 | 2012-12-26|2012-12-30
2 |satyawan  |   lahu@gmail.com|unr  |  Non A/C | R6 |            20002012-01-01|2012-12-07
3 |satyawan  |   lahu@gmail.com|unr  |  Non A/C | R8 |            2013-01-01  |2013-01-10
4 |satyawan  |   lahu@gmail.com|unr  |  Non A/C | R9 |            2013-01-10 |2013-01-16
5 |satyawan  |   lahu@gmail.com|unr  |  Non A/C | R6 |            2013-01-01 |2013-01-20
```

i have fired query on join of this both table for sort data of unbooked rooms. the query is below

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms 
LEFT JOIN customer_booking  
ON customer_booking.room_no = rooms.room_no
WHERE customer_booking.client_id IS NULL
OR (customer_booking.check_out >= 2013-01-01
AND customer_booking.check_in >= 2013-01-10)
OR (customer_booking.check_out <= 2013-01-01
AND customer_booking.check_out <= 2013-01-10)
```

but i want only data of unbooked rooms only.
if rooms is already book then it have to show that this room is already book on this date.

i cant get any idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this query. If the last field `room_customer_id` is 0 then room is free otherwise it shows customer_id who reserved this room.

```
SELECT rooms.*,COALESCE(customer_booking.customer_id,0) room_customer_id
FROM rooms 
LEFT JOIN customer_booking  ON 
   (customer_booking.room_no = rooms.room_no)
   and 
   (
      ('2013-01-01' between customer_booking.check_in and customer_booking.check_out)
      or 
      ('2013-01-10' between customer_booking.check_in and customer_booking.check_out)
      or 
      (customer_booking.check_in between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-10')
    )
```

Comment: Very close... he is looking for a 1st - 10th occupancy range, add the 2013-01-10 between in/out and you should be good.

Comment: @DRapp  I've fixed this query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM rooms AS r WHERE r.room_no NOT IN (
   SELECT cb.room_no FROM customer_booking AS cb WHERE your_checkin_constraints);
```

Comment: subselects are horrible in performance vs an actual LEFT JOIN and testing for null (or not)

Comment: @DRapp: Usually but not always.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT r.room,case when r.room_no is null then 'Available'
    else 'Not Available' end
    FROM rooms r
    LEFT JOIN customer_booking cb 
    ON cb.room_no = r.room_no
    AND cb.check_out <= cur_date()-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, then u 'll get d rooms which are not booked

```
SELECT * FROM room r WHERE 
 not exists (
   SELECT cb.room_no FROM customer_booking cb where cb.room_no=r.room_no);
```